# React SSR : Component renders but URL doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm new to React SSR and I have a lot of questions. I tried searching up some answers but I can't find any regarding this.

Every time a user clicks a link, they will be re-directed to a new page. React is a Single Page Application, so the application simply renders a new component.
However, in my react application, the server renders the new component perfectly, but the URL doesn't change.

Example
What I expected:
URL: http://localhost:8080/
Route: Index
URL: http://localhost:8080/about
Route: About

What's happening:
URL: http://localhost:8080/
Route: Index
URL: http://localhost:8080/
Route: About

I'm almost certain the issue lies with the server.js, but I am unable to pinpoint where.

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

import App from "../src/App";

const PORT = process.env.port || 8080;

const app = express();

const htmlcontents = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

app.use("^/$", (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Some error happened");
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${htmlcontents}</div>`
      )
      .replace("</head>", `${helmet.meta.toString()}</head>`)
      .replace("</head>", `${helmet.title.toString()}</head>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')))

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App launched on ${PORT}`);
});
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { about } from './components/about';
import { ErrorFindingPage } from './components/ErrorFindingPage';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import './custom.css';
const history = createMemoryHistory();
export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <NavMenu />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/about' component={about} />
                        <Route path='/ErrorFindingPage' component={ErrorFindingPage} />
                        <Redirect to="/ErrorFindingPage" />
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Did u take a look to Next.js https://nextjs.org/

Comment: You didnt import BrowserRouter. Can you redefine your import statement like this: `import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router} from  "react-router-dom";`